# Ubuntu Notifications

Tags: notification, pidgin, notify-osd, notification-area, qbittorrent

Suddenly none of my notifications for new messages from Pidgin or completed downloads from qBittorrent show up.
Ubuntu version 16.04
Pidgin version Pidgin 2.10.12
qBittorrent version 3.3.1

Any help please?

Edit: So far I found out that to receive notifications, Pidgin and qBittorrent have to remain opened in the foreground behind whatever other applications I'm using.